# How to display data from the command that I run to the ListView Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, mikrotik

I have a problem with my code, I want to display the results of the command that I run into the `ListView`

This is my code now

```java
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);

        // Untuk menjalankan API Mikrotik
        ApiConnection con = MainActivity.getCon();
        if (con !=null) {
            try {
                List<Map<String, String>> rs = con.execute("/log/print");
                for (Map<String, String> r : rs) {
                    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewLog);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
                }

            } catch (MikrotikApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        return view;
    }
```

I have tried using `System.Out` and data can be displayed

```java
List<Map<String, String>> rs = con.execute("/log/print");
    for (Map<String, String> r : rs) {
        System.out.println(r);
    }
```

Display data with `System.Out`

> 06-08 02:27:32.433 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 00:36:45, .id=*1036}
>   06-08 02:27:32.433 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=40:B0:76:D5:DE:00@wlan1:
>   disconnected, received deauth: sending station leaving (3),
>   topics=wireless,info, time=jun/08 00:50:14, .id=*1037} 06-08
>   02:27:32.433 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2 I/System.out:
>   tag=4, data={message=40:B0:76:D5:DE:00@wlan1: connected, signal
>   strength -51, topics=wireless,info, time=jun/08 00:50:26, .id=*1038}
>   06-08 02:27:32.433 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=wifi_dhcp deassigned 10.10.2.103
>   from 40:B0:76:D5:DE:00, topics=dhcp,info, time=jun/08 00:50:26,
>   .id=*1039} 06-08 02:27:32.433 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=wifi_dhcp assigned 10.10.2.103 to
>   40:B0:76:D5:DE:00, topics=dhcp,info, time=jun/08 00:50:26, .id=*103A}
>   06-08 02:27:32.433 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:11:35, .id=*103B} 06-08 02:27:32.433 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:12:04, .id=*103C}
>   06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.100
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:13:29, .id=*103D}
>   06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:25:07, .id=*103E} 06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:25:37, .id=*103F}
>   06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:26:38, .id=*1040} 06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:27:33, .id=*1041}
>   06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:27:40, .id=*1042} 06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:28:18, .id=*1043}
>   06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:29:00, .id=*1044} 06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:29:15, .id=*1045}
>   06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:30:10, .id=*1046} 06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:30:25, .id=*1047}
>   06-08 02:27:32.434 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:32:21, .id=*1048} 06-08 02:27:32.444 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:32:53, .id=*1049}
>   06-08 02:27:32.444 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:38:08, .id=*104A} 06-08 02:27:32.444 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:39:02, .id=*104B}
>   06-08 02:27:32.445 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:44:38, .id=*104C} 06-08 02:27:32.445 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:44:53, .id=*104D}
>   06-08 02:27:32.445 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged out from
>   10.10.2.107 via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:52:58, .id=*104E} 06-08 02:27:32.445 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user kkp logged in from 10.10.2.107
>   via api, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 01:53:13, .id=*104F}
>   06-08 02:27:32.445 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=user yogahilmi logged in from
>   CC:2D:83:A4:94:B8 via winbox, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08
>   02:03:26, .id=*1050} 06-08 02:27:32.445
>   11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2 I/System.out: tag=4,
>   data={message=user yogahilmi logged out from CC:2D:83:A4:94:B8 via
>   winbox, topics=system,info,account, time=jun/08 02:04:46, .id=*1051}
>   06-08 02:27:32.445 11252-11252/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   I/System.out: tag=4, data={message=wifi_dhcp deassigned 10.10.2.108
>   from CC:2D:83:82:17:57, topics=dhcp,info, time=jun/08 02:19:56,
>   .id=*1052}

Comment: you likely just need a basic listview tutorial

Comment: you can't create the listview within the loop

Answer (score 0):

the Map object r cannot be directly converted to a string. 
Use

```
List<Map<String, String>> rs = con.execute("/log/print");
    for (Map<String, String> r : rs) {
        System.out.println(r.get("put the key here").toString());
    }
```

or if you don't have the keys do this to print all the values

```
 List<Map<String, String>> rs = con.execute("/log/print");
        for (Map<String, String> r : rs) {
            for(String valueStr:r.values()){
                 System.out.println(valueStr);
               }      
        }
```

Update.. use this customAdapter

```
public class text extends ArrayAdapter<Map<String, String>> {

    List<Map<String, String>> rs;

    public text(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Map<String, String>> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.rs = objects;// assigns your map object to rs
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rs.size(); //basically number of Items to be in the listview
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); // this is where you use your data

        // first inflate a custom view from xml

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView =inflater.inflate("custom view here", null); // the custom view

        LinearLayout l=convertView.findViewById("some layoutid inside the custom view");


        // Now below you can use your List
        Map<String, String> r = rs.get(position);
        for (String valueStr : r.values()) {

            TextView t=new TextView(getContext());
            t.setText(valueStr);

            l.addView(t);
        }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me, how to use it for ListView?

Comment: See a sample custom adapter you can use for your listview. You only need one adapter for your listview.  You need more explanation then visit this link https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView